# jQuery UI autocomplete values disappear on button click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have an asp.net web form that is used as a front end for users to build an sql query. The form has a text box on it that uses jQuery autocomplete.

The form also has a radio button list, selecting a radio button changes the datasource of the autocomplete.

Once the user has selected an option in the textbox, they click a button to add that option to the query they are building, the added option is displayed in a different textbox.

However when this add button is clicked the textbox loses all its autocomplete suggested values.

I think it is something to do with posting back but I cant figure it out. I know a potential fix is to get the datasource to populate again on the button click, but as there are a few thousand records in the datasource this does take a few seconds and I dont want to spoil the user experience.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    var availableValues = [ <%= codes %> ];
        $( ".autocompleteMe" ).autocomplete({
            minLength:3,
            source: availableValues
        });
});
```

**Radio Button List** The radio button list that changes the datasource of the autocomplete

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbList" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" OnSelectedIndexChanged="list_changed" AutoPostBack="true" >
    <asp:ListItem onclick="ShowLoading()">item1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem onclick="ShowLoading()">item2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem onclick="ShowLoading()">item3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem onclick="ShowLoading()">item4</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**C#** the code that is run when the selected radio button is changed

```
public string codes = "";

    protected void list_changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Remove all the current values from codes string
        codes = "";

        //Wipe the codes text boxes to ensure there is no codes passed in from previous queries
        txtCode.Text = "";
        txtCodeList.Text = "";

        //Get the value of the selected radio button and assign it for use in the query string
        string choice= rbList.SelectedValue;

        string queryString = string.Format("select description from codes where category = '{0}'",choice);
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(codes))
                    {
                        codes+= "\"" + reader["description"].ToString() + "\"";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        codes += ", \"" + reader["description"].ToString() + "\"";
                    }
                }
            }
        }       

    }
```

**Text boxes** two text boxes, txtCode is the autocomplete and txtCodeList stores selected codes on a button click

```
<div class="input-group" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCode" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control autocompleteMe" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <asp:Button ID="btnAddCode" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" type="button" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAddCode_Click"  Width="75px" />
    </span>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCodeList" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" type="text" required Enabled="false" Text="" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <asp:Button ID="btnRemoveCode" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" type="button" Text="Remove" OnClick="btnRemoveCode_Click" Width="75px" />
    </span>
</div>
```

**C# that runs on add button click** this button click causes the textbox txtCode to lose its suggested values from autocomplete

```
protected void btnAddCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtCodeList.Text == "")
    {
        txtCodeList.Text = txtCode.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        txtCodeList.Text = txtCodeList.Text + "," + txtCode.Text;
    }
        txtCode.Text = "";
}
```